# Set default interface (can't connect to wifi after I set static eth0 configuration)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, routing, network-interface, alpine-linux

I am using Alpine Linux. I was able to connect to wifi via wpa_supplicant until I set a static eth0 configuration making my `/etc/network/interfaces` file appearing as the following

```
auto lo
face lo init loopback

auto wlan0
face wlan0 init manual
    up ip link set $IFACE up
    down ip link set $IFACE down

auto eth0
face eth0 init static
    address 192.168.1.100
    net mask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

Now my ethernet works but if I want to connect to wifi I have to comment the last 5 lines of the file, reboot and then I can connect again (but of course I lose the ability to use the ethernet).

This is the output of `route -n`

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 wlan0
```

and this is the output of `ip route show`

```
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth0 scope link  src 192.168.1.100
192.168.2.0/24 dev wlan0 scope link  src 192.168.2.24
```

I think that the problem is described by the first line of the output of `ip route show`.

How can I make wlan0 the default choice for connection and tell the os to use eth0 when wlan0 is not available?

Comment: I can't work out your network configuration. Somehow, you seem to have two DHCP servers, one on Ethernet issuing 192.168.1.0/24 addresses, the other on WiFi  issuing 192.168.2.0/24 addresses, and only the WiFi router has internet access. Please show a diagram of how your network hardware is connected. It should be possible to give internet access over Ethernet, in which case the WiFi won't be needed, except as a fall-back.

Comment: @AFH The Ethernet is connected to a router which creates a local network without internet access. The WiFi router is another one and dispatch the internet signal. The computer I am showing the configuration of is the only one which has a wired and a wireless adapter, the others only have a wired one and do not need internet

Comment: I've never needed this, but after chasing round the documentation I think you need to add a `scope` parameter to your static definition, and I think it should be `scope link`, but the documentation is unclear and I am not in a position to test your configuration, so you'll need to try this yourself. That one change may be enough, or you may need to change the routing table. It is certainly true that 0.0.0.0 with gateway 192.168.2.1 should be routed to `wlan0`, while `eth0` should be used for 192.168.1.0 with gateway 0.0.0.0 and genmask 255.255.255.0 for access to 192.168.1.0/24 only.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to have two default gateways (for different destination networks) working. 
If you want to have internet access and have access to your internal network at the same time, one option is to have explicit static routes to your internal subnets and let your wifi (internet) router be the only default gateway.

Just comment the "gateway" line and add static routes, may be like:

```
    auto eth0
    face eth0 init static
      address 192.168.1.100
      net mask 255.255.255.0
      up ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 via 192.168.1.1
```

assuming 10.0.0.0/8 describes the rest of you internal network.